How to get the correct joint for a Force Torque simulation in Drake
I'm simulating a force-torque sensor using Drake.
Here is a snippet from my setup, where I have previously added in a model called "xarm_force_torque_sensor" into the plant, and welded it onto the end of my robot.
ft_sensor = plant.GetModelInstanceByName("xarm_force_torque_sensor")

# figure out which joint is the ft_sensor weld joint
joint_idxs = plant.GetJointIndices(ft_sensor)
joints = [ plant.get_mutable_joint(idx) for idx in joint_idxs ]
ft_sensor_weld_joint_idx = None
ft_sensor_weld_joint = None
for idx, joint in zip(joint_idxs, joints):
    if "weld" in joint.name():
        ft_sensor_weld_joint_idx = idx
        ft_sensor_weld_joint = joint
        break
assert ft_sensor_weld_joint is not None

ft_sensor_child_frame = ft_sensor_weld_joint.frame_on_child()
AddFrameTriadIllustration(
    scene_graph=scene_graph,
    frame=ft_sensor_child_frame, length=0.5, name="ft_sensor_weld")

This locates where I want the sensor frame to be, as visualized in the following screenshot.

I am thinking that doing a string search for "weld" is a little brittle, and I am wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to accomplish what I have done.

TBH I don't understand the question at all.  I don't think it's about FT at all really, just about how to find the joint you care about from some model you loaded?  I don't understand the objective function for your selection heuristic.  Does joint_idxs actually have more than one joint in it anyway?  Why does the FT model file have >1 joint?

@jwnimmer-tri You're right, it's more about how to find the joint I care about. The model corresponds to a FT sensor. Actually I didn't realize that physically, there should only be that one weld joint. Thanks for making me realize I was just over complicating things.
